# merge two lists of different objects

Tags: java, android, list, object, merge

i'm using api requests that returns a list.
-the first api request returns a list of object that contains (user_id,content,date,title)
-the second response returns list of object too that contains (user_id,user_name).

i want to merge the two list the display them into one recycler view  but keep user name instead of user_id.this image breaks down what i want clearly.
[image]

apprecuiate any help i'm really stuck in this and i need it ty .

**EDIT**

this is the first api call :

```
    followuplist=new ArrayList<>();


    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    final Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<TraitementTicketModel>> call = api.getfollowup(id, sestoken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TraitementTicketModel>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TraitementTicketModel>> call, Response<List<TraitementTicketModel>> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong !! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: something is wrong");


            } else if (response.body() == null) {

                return;
            }

            List<TraitementTicketModel> followups = response.body();


            for (TraitementTicketModel followup : followups) {


                followuplist.add(followup);

            }


            followuplist.add(firstfollowup());
           

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TraitementTicketModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pas de connextion internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

this is the second api call :

```
      List<User> userList;
      SharedPreferences sp =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("tokenPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sestoken = sp.getString("token","");

    Retrofit retrofit= RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    final Api api= retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<User>> call = api.getUser(sestoken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

            if (response.code() != 200){
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: something is wrong"+response.code() );



            }
            List<User> users = response.body();



            for (User user : users){

                userList.add(user);
            }

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);



        }
```

so  I have two liststhe first one is :
followuplist (user_id,title,content,date)
and the second :
userList(user_id,user_name)
but i didn't know what to do after that to get to my goal

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with and what have you done so far?

Comment: Post your best attempt to solve this.

Comment: Okay i'm going to edit this

Comment: If you can't run a single call to get the info you need (which in SQL would be easy to join on user_id to get all the data at once in one call) then you should organize one of the lists into a map where the user_id is the key and the object is the value. Then it would be easy to run through the list, do the lookup on the map and create your combined object, but again, this seems like a problem that should be solved by the API,

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.
In this example `UserDetails` is the object on the left in your image, `UserInfo` the one on the right, and `MergeData` the result.

You should use Kotlin instead of Java, it's far easier to manipulate lists.

```
 List<MergedData> mergeList(
            List<UserDetails> listUserDetails,
            List<UserInfo> listUserInfo
    ) {

        // Resulting list
        final List<MergedData> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // We iterate through the first list
        for (UserDetails details : listUserDetails) {
            // For each element of the list we will try to find one with the same user id in the other list
            for (UserInfo info : listUserInfo) {
                // if the current element of the second list has the same user id as the current one from the first list, we merge the data in a new object and this object is then added to the result list.
                if (details.getUserId().equals(info.getUserId())) {
                    result.add(
                            new MergedData(
                               info.getName(),
                               details.getContent(),
                               details.getTitre(),
                               details.getDate()
                            )
                    );
                    // Once the object is found it is unnecessary to continue looping though the second list, so we break the for loop.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Once we finished to iterate through the first list, we return the result.
        return result;
    }
```

Same example in Kotlin:

```
fun mergeList(
    listUserDetails: List<UserDetails>,
    listUserInfo: List<UserInfo>
): List<MergedData> =
    listUserDetails.mapNotNull { details ->
        listUserInfo
            .firstOrNull { it.userId == details.userId }
            ?.let { info ->
                MergedData(
                    info.name,
                    details.content,
                    details.titre,
                    details.date
                )
            }
    }
```